# How can I output HTML from a Google Apps Script?

Tags: html, google-apps-script, web-applications

I have this simple script to get a page and output it unchanged. However, the browser doesn't recognize the output as HTML and shows it as text.

```
function doGet(e) {
  var url = e.queryString || "";
  if (url != "") {
    return getPage(url);
  }  
  return "not found";
}

function test() {
  return getPage("www.google.com");
}

function getPage(url) {
  var options = {
    headers : {'Cache-Control' : 'max-age=0'}
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var html = response.getContent();
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(html).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.HTML);
}
```

What's wrong? How can I output the fetched page as HTML?

Comment: Hmm, HTML isn't on the list of valid mime types at: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/mime-type

Comment: I really have no idea, but look here:  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this return in your `getPage()` function instead:

```
var html = response.getContentText();
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
```

However, do not expect the fetched page to be "unchanged" - HTML Service will sanitize the content, which may result in some page functionality being removed or not working.

Also keep in mind that your web app is rendered inside an `iframe` - your fetched page may not allow it to be run in an iframe or employ a frame-breakout javascript which may result in your users being redirected away from your web app to the actual url of the fetched page.

I must ask, though: are you certain you *must* render the external page this way? Wouldn't a simple `<a href="..." target="_blank">link to external page (will open in a new tab/window)</a>` suffice?

Comment: "Wouldn't a simple..." This is to fetch a page that may be blocked. I changed the `return` to use your suggestion, but now all I get is a variable length string of comma separated integers for each page fetched. Here's a small sample of what appears to be ASCII values when fetching http://stackoverflow.com: `60,33,68,79,67,84,89,80,69,32,104,116,109,108,62,13,10,60,104,116,109,108,62,13,10,60,104,101,97,100,62,13,10,32,32,32,32,13,10,32,32,32,32,60,116,105,116,108,101,62,83,116,97,99,107,32,79,118,101,114,102,108,111,119,60,47,116,105,116,108,101,62,13,10,32,32,32,32,60,108,105,110,107,32,114`

Comment: Sorry, it should be `.getContentText()` instead of `.getContent()`. I have edited the code in my answer as well.